# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float")

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that prints the area, perimeter, and diagonal of a rectangle I am analyzing.

**This is the part of the code that is returning an error:**

```
number2 = int(input(" Enter Width: "));

print("The area of the rectangle: " + str(number1 * number2));
print("The perimeter of the rectangle: " + str(number1 * 2 + number2 *2));

import math

print("The length of the diagonal: " + math.sqrt(number1**2 + number2**2))
```

**The error which I am receiving:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-09f680f30f33> in <module>
      7 import math
      8 
----> 9 print("The length of the diagonal: " + math.sqrt(number1**2 + number2**2))

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Comment: print("The length of the diagonal: " + str(math.sqrt(number1**2 + number2**2)))

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.sqrt` returns a float, which you are trying to append to the string `"The length of diagonal:"`. Here a couple of options

### Use args of `print()`

```
print("The length of the diagonal:", math.sqrt(number1**2 + number2**2))
```

### Format the result of `math.sqrt`

```
print("The length of the diagonal: {}".format(math.sqrt(number1**2 + number2**2))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: If it worked for you, can you mark it as the answer?

Comment: Starting with python 3.6 you can also use f-strings, my favourite solution: `print(f"The length of the diagonal: {math.sqrt(number1**2 + number2**2)}"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a formatted string

either old way:

```py
print("The length of the diagonal: {0}".format(math.sqrt(number1**2 + number2**2)))
```

Note that the `0` is not required in this case but can be used to specify the index in the arg tuple to `.format()`.

or using the newer f-string:

```py
print(f"The length of the diagonal: {math.sqrt(number1**2 + number2**2)}")
```